# XSLT: ranking of elements and computation

Tags: xml, xslt

I apologize for being totally inexperienced with XML, but solving this problem will help me to understand how computation with XSLT works.

We have a sample database structured like this:

```
<HospitalML>
<Patients>
    <Patient>
        <Name>
            <FirstName>Salvatore</FirstName>
            <LastName>Piscuoglio</LastName>
        </Name>
        <Diagnoses>
            <Diagnosis>
                <Name>HCC</Name>
                <Weight>1.2</Weight>
            </Diagnosis>
            <Diagnosis>
                <Name>CRC</Name>
                <Weight>2.2</Weight>
            </Diagnosis>
        </Diagnoses>
    </Patient>
</Patients>
<Hospitals>
    <Hospital>
        <HospitalName>LondonGeneral</HospitalName>
        <Diagnoses>
            <Diagnosis>
                <Name>HCC</Name>
                <Weight>2.1</Weight>
            </Diagnosis>
            <Diagnosis>
                <Name>CRC</Name>
                <Weight>0.2</Weight>
            </Diagnosis>
        </Diagnoses>
    </Hospital>
    <Hospital>
        <HospitalName>EastEnd</HospitalName>
        <Diagnoses>
            <Diagnosis>
                <Name>HCC</Name>
                <Weight>1.7</Weight>
            </Diagnosis>
            <Diagnosis>
                <Name>CRC</Name>
                <Weight>0.7</Weight>
            </Diagnosis>
        </Diagnoses>
    </Hospital>
</Hospitals>
```

Each patient has a set of diagnoses with "weight" values indicating how severe they are. 
Each hospital element has "diagnoses"child elements indicating which diseases they manage and a "weight" element scores indicating how good they are at each.

I would like to evaluate hospitals from the database for patient Salvatore and give a list of hospitals ranked up by scores indicating the best ones for his diagnoses.

Would be grateful for any thoughts. Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to use an XSLT 2.0 processor (like Saxon 9) and XSLT 2.0 to solve that or an XSLT 1.0 processor with XSLT 1.0?

Comment: Thank you for quick reply. XSLT 1.0 is preferred.

Comment: How would you define "the best ones for his diagnoses"? The bes hospitals for each individual diagnosis, or for the set of all of his diagnosis? What metrics is to be used in the latter case?

Answer (score 0):

This xslt :

```
    <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <!-- You could select one specific patient instead of all if you prefer.-->
        <xsl:apply-templates select=".//Patient"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- This template just copy a patient and his name and 'do the job' for all the diagnoses. -->
    <xsl:template match="Patient">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="Name"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="Diagnoses/Diagnosis"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Here is the template for the patient diagnosis (the predicate is just there to prevent mistakes with diagnosis element child of hospital) -->
    <xsl:template match="Diagnosis[ancestor::Patient]">
        <!-- we store the name and weight inside variables to simplify the xpaths below.
            Actually you may use the current() function, but was'nt sure about its support in XSLT 1.0-->
        <xsl:variable name="name" select="Name"/>
        <xsl:variable name="patientWeight" select="Weight"/>
        <!-- first statement, copy the diagnosis and its name. -->
        <xsl:copy>        
            <xsl:copy-of select="Name"/>
            <!-- then, search for hospitals which got same diagnosis -->
            <xsl:apply-templates select="//Hospital[.//Diagnosis/Name = $name]">
                <!-- sort them by their weight in the current diagnosis. This is the "real job", where you got your hospital 'rank' for a diagnosis.  -->
                <xsl:sort select=".//Diagnosis[Name = $name]/Weight" order="descending"/>
                <!-- use this param to be able to output only the weight of the current diagnosis -->
                <xsl:with-param name="diagnosis" select="$name"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="patientWeight" select="$patientWeight"/> 
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- A simple template, that just output the hospital, its name and its weight score (aka : hospital weight * patient weight.  -->
    <xsl:template match="Hospital">
        <xsl:param name="diagnosis"/>
        <xsl:param name="patientWeight"/>
        <xsl:element name="Weight">                   
        <xsl:value-of select="number(.//Diagnosis[Name=$diagnosis]/Weight) * $patientWeight"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Provide this xml output :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Patient>
   <Name>

      <FirstName>Salvatore</FirstName>

      <LastName>Piscuoglio</LastName>

   </Name>
   <Diagnosis>
      <Name>HCC</Name>
      <Hospital>
         <HospitalName>LondonGeneral</HospitalName>
         <Weight>2.52</Weight>
      </Hospital>
      <Hospital>
         <HospitalName>EastEnd</HospitalName>
         <Weight>2.04</Weight>
      </Hospital>
   </Diagnosis>
   <Diagnosis>
      <Name>CRC</Name>
      <Hospital>
         <HospitalName>EastEnd</HospitalName>
         <Weight>1.54</Weight>
      </Hospital>
      <Hospital>
         <HospitalName>LondonGeneral</HospitalName>
         <Weight>0.44</Weight>
      </Hospital>
   </Diagnosis>
</Patient>
```

You may change the output format just by switching the xsl:copy and xsl:copy-of calls with your personnal output format.

Hope this will help.

Comment: Thanks Eric and Dimitre. Apologize for not being entirely clear what I wanted, but since our patient has two diagnoses I would consider his health as value of the 1st diagnosis multiplied by 2nd. Then efficacy of treatment at each hospital can be evaluated similarly. In our case, the East End Hospital performs slightly better (1.7*0.7) compared to the London General (2.1*0.2). I would like to design XSLT stylesheet with output to XHTML that would simply calculate the value for a patient and hospitals and then output the list of hospitals sorted by their rank values.

Comment: I edited my answer to handle youre "weight scoring" in the outputs.
Is this fixing your issue ?

Comment: Thanks, but it's not working. Element "weight" from template "Hospital" should not be self-closing and .//Diagnosis[Name=$diagnosis]/Name) should not have round bracket at the end. But even fixing this does not output any values.

Comment: Ok, you catch me. I edited the xslt inside the post without testing it another time... Bugs corrected, should output the weight score now (aka : patientWeight*hospitalWeight). Just had completely miswritten the Xpath for the weigth score calcul.

Comment: Thanks, almost there. Now we get ratings for each diagnosis for each hospital. All that needs to be done is to add CRC+HCC values for each hospital, output the value, and sort hospitals based on the resulting score. Because at the moment we are getting for CRC value X for hospital A and value Y for hospital B, and for HCC value Z for hosp. A and value W for hosp. B. So X+Z should make the final ranking for hospital A and Y+W  for hospital B.

Comment: Arf... Dimitre was smarter than me... In XSLT 1.0 what you need is quite tricky, because you need to calculate the rank first in a variable and sort it based on the value of this variable. In xslt 1.0, you'll need the node-set() function which comes with some extensions. If you're really stucked, i'll try to give you more but when I have time (a quick way could be 2 transformations, one for the rank calcul, one for the sort). But with XSLT 2.0 it would be easier.

Comment: Thanks Eric. Yes, I am quite stuck. But if XSLT2.0 solves the problem, then please feel free to use it.